# Checking you have correct Date type at runtime for comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

OK so it's runtime.  You are trying to compare Date's in JavaScript.  Now sometimes in your code Dates are Strings, sometimes they are Dates and sometimes they are JQuery Objects wrapping around dates - what is returned from `DatePicker.parseDate` see: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

So before you just do:

```
date1 < date2 ...
```

You want to ensure both dates are in the correct format, JQuery date object i.e. what is returned from `DatePicker.parseDate()`.

What is your suggestion for doing this?

Comment: What about doing a truthy check to see both have isMonth() ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to do a truthy on the date variables

e.g.

```
myDate.getMonth()
```